# Magento 2 Open Source custom module or third party extension would be work in Magento 2 Enterprise Cloud Edition?

Tags: magento2

I am having a custom payment module developed in Magento 2 Open Source. It will works in Magento Enterprise Cloud? The source code for both the editions will differ?

Comment: You have raised a good point. +1 for that

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: As you told, I have contacted the Magento team. They sent me a Google form to make a request to access the Enterprise Cloud Sandbox. I submitted the request and still waiting.

Answer (score 1):

I had personally tried some extensions of **Community edition** in my **Enterprise Edition** and it worked perfectly,

However, if the third party module developer restricted it to work on community only, to sell enterprise module on high price then it wont work on your enterprise edition.

You need to try it on your local environment first

Comment: Good to hear that some extensions of Community Edition are worked in Enterprise Edition. I know it is paid edition but how to get the Enterprise Edition source code to try it in my local environment?

Comment: Magento will not hesitate to share enterprise source code for your local setup. I am using enterprise edition, and I have local and staging setup. You can contact magento support to get code, or you can get it from enterprise portal

Answer (score 1):

There is not any such difference in coding in Enterprise Edition.

Although it should work but I think it would be better if you test it in any Magneto Enterprise Edition first (on your local environment).

Because Magento Enterprise Edition comes with additional features and number of other modules itself that are not present in Community Edition, so there may be some possibility of conflict of your module with Magento Enterprise Edition modules.